# How do I hide the cursor on hover of a scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

If I use

```
* {
    cursor: none!important;
}
```

on my webpage, the cursor still appears whenever hovering over a scroll bar. I can hide the scrollbar to prevent this but how do I hide only the cursor and not the scroll bar?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't this confuse the user into thinking they don't have the ability to scroll?

Comment: I have a custom cursor to show scrollability. I just don't want the default cursor to appear

Comment: So position a fixed element over the entire page and disable scrolling on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using jQuery "jscrollpane"

You have to add at the first **jscrollpane.css**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jScrollPane/2.1.0/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
```

Then called jQuery file and the other files

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jScrollPane/2.1.0/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js"></script>
```

> As well as you can change the cursor, you only have to change this code
>   in css `cursor: zoom-in !important;` to `cursor: none !important;` if
>   you want to hide the cursor.

**In:**

```
.jspDrag {
    background: #FF5722;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: zoom-in !important;
}
```

Here you go

```js
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane')
        .jScrollPane()
        .bind(
            'mousewheel',
            function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        );
});
```

```css
.scroll-pane
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.scroll-pane p
{
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.jspTrack {
    background: #0f7;
    position: relative;
}
.jspDrag {
    background: #FF5722;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: zoom-in !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jScrollPane/2.1.0/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jScrollPane/2.1.0/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

 <div class="scroll-pane">
                <p>Vivamus  hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus  rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie  magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum  feugiat nisl ut dapibus.</p>
                <p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam pulvinar, odio sed rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat purus metus eu velit. Proin metus odio, aliquam eget molestie nec, gravida ut sapien. Phasellus quis est sed turpis sollicitudin venenatis sed eu odio. Praesent eget neque eu eros interdum malesuada non vel leo. Sed fringilla porta ligula egestas tincidunt. Nullam risus magna, ornare vitae varius eget, scelerisque a libero. Morbi eu porttitor ipsum. Nullam lorem nisi, posuere quis volutpat eget, luctus nec massa. Pellentesque aliquam lacinia tellus sit amet bibendum. Ut posuere justo in enim pretium scelerisque. Etiam ornare vehicula euismod. Vestibulum at risus augue. Sed non semper dolor. Sed fringilla consequat velit a porta. Pellentesque sed lectus pharetra ipsum ultricies commodo non sit amet velit. Suspendisse volutpat lobortis ipsum, in scelerisque nisi iaculis a. Duis pulvinar lacinia commodo. Integer in lorem id nibh luctus aliquam. Sed elementum, est ac sagittis porttitor, neque metus ultricies ante, in accumsan massa nisl non metus. Vivamus sagittis quam a lacus dictum tempor. Nullam in semper ipsum. Cras a est id massa malesuada tincidunt. Etiam a urna tellus. Ut rutrum vehicula dui, eu cursus magna tincidunt pretium. Donec malesuada accumsan quam, et commodo orci viverra et. Integer tincidunt sagittis lectus. Mauris ac ligula quis orci auctor tincidunt. Suspendisse odio justo, varius id.</p>
                <p>Vivamus luctus urna sed urna ultricies ac tempor dui sagittis. In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla, orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim. Morbi euismod magna ac lorem rutrum elementum. Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum. Etiam scelerisque, nunc ac egestas consequat, odio nibh euismod.</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to change the cursor for the 'browser scrollbar' by using CSS alone

> because CSS is only supposed to effect the contents of the browser
>   window and not the browser interface itself.

Comment: but the browser scrollbar is part of the browser window?

Comment: can you change your answer to reflect that comment please

Comment: @LoveenDyall yes sure, I'll change it